# Create circle Path

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I need to create a circle path. I am using code below

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(float x, float y, radious, Path.Direction);
```

But my circle path is start always from point zero.
[image]

Is there any way to set angle? and starting from 180 degrees?

Comment: so you need an "arc", not "circle" - read `Path` class documentation for more info

Comment: Dou you mean you want to draw a circle with animation effect? like this? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507887/draw-a-circle-on-canvas-using-animation/53537156#53537156

Comment: Yes, but i need to set start point(x,y), start Angle and radious. In arc i need to set RectF. In rectF i need to set tob,bot,left,right. I need to set only x,y

Comment: this is because you can draw arcs of circles and arcs of ovals - thats why you need a `RectF`

Comment: btw what kind of problems do you have in setting the right `RectF` if you have center_x, center_y and radius?

Comment: Is there any code which i can set x,y directly?

Comment: no, drawing an arc requires bounding rectangle, what problems do you have with **RectF**?

Comment: Should i find RectF from x,y? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184561/discussion-between-dim-and-pskink).